# Mouse becomes unresponsive on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, mouse

I dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 (on a HP Pavillion Touchsmart 15 Notebook PC 15-n090sa, bought in 2014). I use Ubuntu every day, and rarely boot up Windows.

I use an optical mouse that is attached to my computer by USB cable.

Manufacturer: TRUST (www.trust.com)
Model: AMI MOUSE 250S OPTICAL.

It has a left-click button, a right-click button and a scrollwheel between them that is clickable.

The mouse works perfectly on Windows. But on Ubuntu, it will work OK for a couple of seconds, but then become less and less responsive, to the point where it barely works at all.

I have a touchpad that works perfectly in both Windows and Ubuntu.

There is a lot of extra information in this bug report I submitted through "ubuntu-bug xorg" and "xdiagnose" here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1832133

Please help!

**Update #1:**

```
tom@Hoppy:~$ xinput -list

Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]

- Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]

- ELAN Touchscreen                          id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]

- SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]

- HID 1241:1111                             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]

Virtual core keyboard                       id=3    [master keyboard (2)]

- Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]

- HP Truevision HD: HP Truevision           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]

- HP WMI hotkeys                            id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]

- HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]

- AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]

- Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]

- Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]

- Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

**Update #2:**

tom@Hoppy:~$ xinput --list-props 9

Device 'HID 1241:1111':

```
Device Enabled (147):   1

Coordinate Transformation Matrix (149): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000

libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (286):   0

libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (287):   0

libinput Scroll Methods Available (288):    0, 0, 1

libinput Scroll Method Enabled (289):   0, 0, 0

libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (290):   0, 0, 0

libinput Button Scrolling Button (291): 2

libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (292): 2

libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (293):    0

libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (294):    0

libinput Accel Speed (295): -0.438849

libinput Accel Speed Default (296): 0.000000

libinput Accel Profiles Available (297):    1, 1

libinput Accel Profile Enabled (298):   1, 0

libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (299):   1, 0

libinput Left Handed Enabled (300): 0

libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (301): 0

libinput Send Events Modes Available (271): 1, 0

libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (272):    0, 0

libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (273):    0, 0

Device Node (274):  "/dev/input/event11"

Device Product ID (275):    4673, 4369

libinput Drag Lock Buttons (302):   <no items>

libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (303):   1
```

Comment: You can try reloading the mouse driver: `sudo modprobe -r psmouse` and then `modprobe psmouse`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: thank you, I tried that. But it hasn't worked...

Comment: can you run `xinput -list` and then copy and paste the text lines (not a screen shot) into your question?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: thanks, that is done now. Unless I am mistaken, I can't see the mouse in the list of input devices (even though it is plugged in, and working poorly)

Comment: It could be `id=9`. You can use `xinput --list-props 9` to find out more about this device. It's showing as a Blekin Mouse: https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/1241/device/1122 You can edit your USB table to change 1241:1111 to display a more meaningful name.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: It definitely was id=9 (this disappeared from the xinput -list when I unplugged it). I have used the code you suggested, and pasted the response into my answer.

Comment: I don't know how to edit my USB table, and don't know if it's necessary right now. I see what you mean about the Belkin mouse, but "Trust" is written all over it. I don't know what to say about that.

Comment: No you don't need to edit the USB name table. It's good enough to know that 1241:1111 is your mouse. I've never had a broken mouse so this about exhausts what I can contribute. Hopefully those experienced with `libinput` and broken mice will come along to offer assistance.

Comment: If by chance you installed Laptop Tools it can disable mouse to save power: https://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/06/fix-usb-mouse-not-working-laptop-mode-tools-ubuntu/

Comment: No, I haven't installed Laptop Tools. Disabling the mouse does not solve my problem.